# ubuntu 14.10 shows kernel panic error on startup after upgrade from 14.04

Tags: upgrade, kernel, ati, 14.10

i upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10, when prompted by the system update utility
during the upgrade some packages did not install properly / gave errors (i cant remember which packages)
after restart it could not connect to wired internet/ethernet 
i tried auto eth0, but it said i did not have sufficient priveleges
so i tried to restart again
i selected shut-down from the panel
neither restart or shut-down buttons on the pop up worked
manually restarted but same problem

restarted in safe mode and fixed packages, reloaded grub, enabled networking
after that it freezes while restarting and gives kernel panic error

my configuration is:
processor AMD X4 965
graphics  ATI Radeon HD5850
mother board Asus M4A87TD USB3